# The best way for deferred execution in serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, serverless, serverless-framework

I have serverless microservices using API gateway/lambda/dynamodb. We have a stream of measurements coming in from Kinesis and if an alarm condition is detected, it needs to be triggered after x seconds. What's the best way to trigger a task after x seconds in this case? X is configurable by the user for different conditions and cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help
[How do I delay processing of AWS Kinesis messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160627/how-do-i-delay-processing-of-aws-kinesis-messages)

1. use SQS delay message
2. delay x seconds in lambda, if it is not too long(max 15min for a lambda to run)

Comment: SQS delay would be a constant at the queue level. The delay here is configurable by the users

Comment: Besides the delay can be a lot longer than 15 mins.